# Concatenate CSVs into dataframe based on timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, glob

I have a dir of subdirs that contain CSVs, and I want to concatenate those into a single dataframe. But I only want to do so with files that are the 'the most recently' exported based on a timestamp in the filename.

For example, this is a list of files contained in various sub-dirs:

```
FileA_20230208_ExportedOn_20230202T0215Z
FileA_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T0015Z
FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230205T0215Z
FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2218Z
FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20210208T0215Z
FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20230201T0215Z
FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2208Z
FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20200207T0215Z
FileA_20230209_ExportedOn_20230202T1915Z
FileA_20230209_ExportedOn_20230202T0215Z
```

So the final dataframe should be a concatenation of just these 4 files:

```
FileA_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T0015Z
FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2218Z
FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2208Z
FileA_20230209_ExportedOn_20230202T1915Z
```

I can concatente all of them by doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Dir of CSVs
files = glob.glob('/**/*.csv', recursive=True)

# Combine all CSVs into single CSV
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp).assign(file_name=Path(fp).name)
                for fp in files], ignore_index=True)
```

But how do I select only the most recently timestamped files?

Comment: You'll have to give a specific definition of recent. "4 most recent"? "In the last month?" You need a file name parser to put the dates into a list after converting them to a timestamp form and then sort on your definition of recent. IMO pandas isn't really important in this.

Comment: @VikramRaghu 4 most recent can be determined by the timestamp in the filename

Answer (score 0):

Use `.sort()` on your file list to get the newest files (the timestamps are lexicographically comparable, so we don't need to parse them further) in reverse order, then slice the list to get the 4 first ones:

```
files = [  # e.g. glob.glob('/**/*.csv', recursive=True)
    "FileA_20230208_ExportedOn_20230202T0215Z.csv",
    "FileA_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T0015Z.csv",
    "FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230205T0215Z.csv",
    "FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2218Z.csv",
    "FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20210208T0215Z.csv",
    "FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20230201T0215Z.csv",
    "FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2208Z.csv",
    "FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20200207T0215Z.csv",
    "FileA_20230209_ExportedOn_20230202T1915Z.csv",
    "FileA_20230209_ExportedOn_20230202T0215Z.csv",
]

files.sort(key=lambda name: name.partition("ExportedOn_")[2], reverse=True)
print(files[:4])
```

prints out

```
[
 'FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2218Z.csv', 
 'FileC_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2208Z.csv', 
 'FileA_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T0015Z.csv', 
 'FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230205T0215Z.csv',
]
```

(i.e. I think your example had missed there's an export from 20230205 :) )

Comment: It won't always be the 4-most recent though; rather, it should just be *the* most recently timestamped file per everything preceding `ExportedOn`.

Comment: But `FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230208T2218Z.csv ` is more recent than `FileB_20230208_ExportedOn_20230205T0215Z.csv`, so it should not be included in the final list.

Comment: @user53526356 In that case, you'll need to specify what you need better in your post - there are two timestamps in each filename.